# Ekiga under Windows: registered but calls fail

Tags: voip, sip

I have a VoIP account with sub-accounts. Sub-accounts are assigned 3-digit extensions and I can call between sub-accounts using regular desktop phones connected to my ATA. Now I am trying to set up Ekiga to do the same on the PCs which are on the same LAN as the ATA.

When I run Ekiga and create a SIP account using one of the sub-account credentials, it shows in Ekiga as "Registered". But when I try to place a call to another sub-account which is used by one of desktop phones on the ATA, those Ekiga calls always fail.

Looking at logs collected using `ekiga -d 4` command, I can see that it is trying to connect using the physical NIC's IP, but also on the VirtualBox's virtual interface's IP. Could that be the reason the calls do not go through?

The logs can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/eiatiTVw) and I appreciate if anyone can point to an issue which would explain what I am doing wrong!

Comment: A downvote for... Complete the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using XLite. It should just work out of the box. Any (even old) versions would do.

Comment: Tried Xlite 3.0 and it worked out of the box.